# Parsing Tweets in ColdFusion

Tags: parsing, twitter, coldfusion, rss

I have an RSS feed that I am working on in ColdFusion 8.  What I would like to do is parse the entire RSS feed and pull out trending words.

I would like my output to display how many times each word is used.  Much like a word cloud.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Did you have a specific question?

Comment: <cfset feedurl="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/47847839.rss" />

<cffeed
    source="#feedurl#"
    properties="feedmeta"
    query="feeditems" />
<ol>

<cfoutput query="feeditems">
    <li>#content#</li>
</cfoutput>
</ol>

I want my CFloop to pull out trending words from the RSS feed.

Comment: And which part of that are you have trouble with, exactly? Can you post the code in question?

Comment: The CfLoop is where I am having trouble. It is as follows: <cfloop list="feedurl"
  delimiters=" "
  index="feeditems">

<cfoutput>#feeditems#</cfoutput>

</cfloop>

It only displays the word "feeditems" when executed.  I want my CfLoop to loop through the rss feed and pull out all of the individual words. In this way, I want to be able to see trending topics from the RSS feed.

I am sorry that I'm not too specific, I am new to Cold Fusion and web development in general.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your code, rather than here in the comments where it's harder to read. First thing I see is that the URL for feedurl is not valid. First thing to do is make sure you're getting data in. Try a CFDUMP right after the CFFEED to ensure you're getting data in.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this [article](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/9/14/Building-a-Twitter-Report-in-ColdFusion).  Ray Camden walks through a Twitter Report.  He uses everyting you should need to search, parse and output from Twitter.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to go to http://riaforge.org/ and download a ColdFusion Twitter API package and invest some time solving your challenge.